# Error with asammdf: "error: unpack requires a buffer of 56 bytes"

Tags: python, mdf, canape, asammdf

I am using the asammdf package to load MDF file.  The code below works for only some of my MDF files.  Many files give me the error below.  I am able to open the file in CANape with no issues.

Load files in a desktop app (this works)

```
from asammdf import MDF
mdf = MDF(r'\\Stnafddco123.us123.corpintra.net\veh_test\Vehicles_Data_and_Truck_Info\APTIV_logger_data\1FUJHLDR8KLXXXXXX_Trip-Detail_2019-07-16 15-18-25.mf4')
mdf
```

---

```
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-c9001bcab2a9> in <module>()
      1 from asammdf import MDF
----> 2 mdf = MDF(r'\\Stnafddco123.us123.corpintra.net\veh_test\Vehicles_Data_and_Truck_Info\APTIV_logger_data\1FUJHLDR8KLXXXXXX_Trip-Detail_2019-07-16 15-18-25.mf4')
      3 mdf

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\asammdf\mdf.py in __init__(self, name, version, **kwargs)
    124                 self._mdf = MDF3(name, **kwargs)
    125             elif version in MDF4_VERSIONS:
--> 126                 self._mdf = MDF4(name, **kwargs)
    127             elif version in MDF2_VERSIONS:
    128                 self._mdf = MDF2(name, **kwargs)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\asammdf\blocks\mdf_v4.py in __init__(self, name, version, **kwargs)
    247                     self._file = mmap.mmap(x.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
    248                     self._from_filelike = False
--> 249                     self._read(mapped=True)
    250 
    251                     self._file.close()

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\asammdf\blocks\mdf_v4.py in _read(self, mapped)
    415                 # Read channels by walking recursively in the channel group
    416                 # starting from the first channel
--> 417                 self._read_channels(ch_addr, grp, stream, dg_cntr, ch_cntr, mapped=mapped)
    418 
    419                 cg_addr = channel_group.next_cg_addr

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\asammdf\blocks\mdf_v4.py in _read_channels(self, ch_addr, grp, stream, dg_cntr, ch_cntr, channel_composition, mapped)
    760                 at_map=self._attachments_map,
    761                 use_display_names=self._use_display_names,
--> 762                 mapped=mapped,
    763             )
    764 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\asammdf\blocks\v4_blocks.py in __init__(self, **kwargs)
    606                         conv = ChannelConversion(
    607                             raw_bytes=raw_bytes, stream=stream, address=address,
--> 608                             mapped=mapped,
    609                         )
    610                         cc_map[raw_bytes] = conv

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\asammdf\blocks\v4_blocks.py in __init__(self, **kwargs)
   2010                     self.min_phy_value,
   2011                     self.max_phy_value,
-> 2012                 ) = v4c.CONVERSION_NONE_INIT_u(block)
   2013 
   2014             elif conv == v4c.CONVERSION_TYPE_LIN:

error: unpack requires a buffer of 56 bytes
```

Comment: Please share your MDF file otherwise your problem can't be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see any errors when you open the file with MDFValidator?

Comment: Yes. I tried MDF Validator after I made this post and did notice the files that would not load withe asammdf had errors.  It seems there are issues with some of the data groups/blocks.  I think this is the issue with loading.  It is interesting that a desktop app like CANape will load these files and ignore the error but the Python package will not.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think that CANape just silently ignores the errors related to channel conversions. I will push some changes next week to the development branch of asammdf

Comment: I look forward to trying the changes.  Thank you!